# CMake fails to add fPIC compile option

Tags: qt, cmake, qt5, fpic

I am having some issues trying to link an executable which transitively uses Qt5. 
I have configured my project using CMake with the option `CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE = ON` but still, when compiling the executable, Qt5 complains that I should use `fPIC`.

```
[ 99%] Building CXX object tools/deSimRunner/CMakeFiles/deSimRunner.dir/main.cpp.o
cd /home/jjcasmar/projects/Hybrid/Desilico/prj/Release/tools/deSimRunner && /home/jjcasmar/usr/local/bin/c++  -DBOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK -DFMT_SHARED -DHAVE_CUDA -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DSPDLOG_COMPILED_LIB -DSPDLOG_FMT_EXTERNAL -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1 -I/home/jjcasmar/projects/Hybrid/Desilico/src/deCore -I/home/jjcasmar/projects/Hybrid/Desilico/src/deCore/.. -I/home/jjcasmar/projects/Hybrid/Desilico/src/deGeom/.. -I/opt/cuda/include -I/home/jjcasmar/projects/Hybrid/Desilico/src/deSim/.. -isystem /home/jjcasmar/.conan/data/eigen/3.3.7/conan/stable/package/5ab84d6acfe1f23c4fae0ab88f26e3a396351ac9/include/eigen3 -isystem /home/jjcasmar/.conan/data/rapidjson/1.1.0/bincrafters/stable/package/5ab84d6acfe1f23c4fae0ab88f26e3a396351ac9/include -isystem /home/jjcasmar/.conan/data/boost/1.71.0/conan/stable/package/393cfc058d5be864014f06fc0bb0e29c6845d9e9/include -isystem /home/jjcasmar/.conan/data/zlib/1.2.11/conan/stable/package/1d877a3df840030e6a8abb74c5ffb9088d08b47a/include -isystem /home/jjcasmar/.conan/data/bzip2/1.0.8/conan/stable/package/a5875aed3fc7ae8dd0488f7e5e99acbc480d721d/include -isystem /usr/include/qt -isystem /usr/include/qt/QtCore -isystem /usr/lib/qt/mkspecs/linux-g++ -isystem /home/jjcasmar/.conan/data/spdlog/1.4.2/bincrafters/stable/package/f31849fd5982a882fc905666fe297f0c231b10af/include -isystem /home/jjcasmar/.conan/data/fmt/6.0.0/bincrafters/stable/package/ca4b767114c8e107f72671a3380d9917e2b9adff/include -isystem /home/jjcasmar/.conan/data/OpenMesh/7.1/desilico/stable/package/b80d46004713aa37d6a90b42e2a326a056a237b5/include -isystem /home/jjcasmar/.conan/data/nanoflann/1.3.0/desilico/stable/package/5ab84d6acfe1f23c4fae0ab88f26e3a396351ac9/include -isystem /home/jjcasmar/usr/local/include -isystem /home/jjcasmar/.conan/data/cereal/1.2.2/conan/stable/package/5ab84d6acfe1f23c4fae0ab88f26e3a396351ac9/include -isystem /home/jjcasmar/.conan/data/glm/0.9.9.5/g-truc/stable/package/5ab84d6acfe1f23c4fae0ab88f26e3a396351ac9/include -isystem /usr/include/qt/QtGui -isystem /home/jjcasmar/.conan/data/range-v3/0.9.1/ericniebler/stable/package/5ab84d6acfe1f23c4fae0ab88f26e3a396351ac9/include  -fopenmp  -O3 -DNDEBUG -fPIE   -DNON_COMMERCIAL_LICENSE -std=gnu++14 -o CMakeFiles/deSimRunner.dir/main.cpp.o -c /home/jjcasmar/projects/Hybrid/Desilico/tools/deSimRunner/main.cpp
In file included from /usr/include/qt/QtCore/qjsonvalue.h:43,
                 from /usr/include/qt/QtCore/qjsondocument.h:43,
                 from /usr/include/qt/QtCore/QJsonDocument:1,
                 from /home/jjcasmar/projects/Hybrid/Desilico/tools/deSimRunner/main.cpp:23:
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qglobal.h:1204:4: error: #error "You must build your code with position independent code if Qt was built with -reduce-relocations. " "Compile your code with -fPIC (-fPIE is not enough)."
 #  error "You must build your code with position independent code if Qt was built with -reduce-relocations. "\
```

I have these two options enabled in my main CMakeLists.txt file

```
set(CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)
set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS ON)
```

How should I correctly add the `fPIC` option for my final executable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your error states:

> "You must build your code with position independent code if Qt was built with -reduce-relocations. " **"Compile your code with -fPIC (-fPIE is not enough)."**

However, your compilation flags only contain `fPIE`, not `fPIC`:

> /usr/local/bin/c++  -DBOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK ...
>   ...
>   -fopenmp  -O3 -DNDEBUG **-fPIE**   -DNON_COMMERCIAL_LICENSE -std=gnu++14 -o CMakeFiles/deSimRunner.dir/main.cpp.o -c /home/jjcasmar/projects/Hybrid/Desilico/tools/deSimRunner/main.cpp

You were correct to try using [`CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE.html), but this variable may not set the flags you expect. The fairly undocumented behavior for this variable is [this](https://github.com/arsenm/sanitizers-cmake/issues/13#issuecomment-315532253):

> - If the target is a **library**, the flag `-fPIC` is added by CMake to the compilation and linker steps.
> - If the target is an **executable**, the flag `-fPIE` is added by CMake to the compilation and linker steps.

Thus, you will have to add the `-fPIC` flag for your **executable** somewhat manually, with something like this:

```
add_executable(deSimRunner ... )
target_compile_options(deSimRunner PRIVATE -fPIC)
```

Comment: I have done exactly that and it works. I guess the problem here is that Qt5::Core adds fPIC, but I had to change it to use POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE because the target that was linking to it was also linking to CUDA and nvcc fails if it sees fPIC. Probably need to rework the dependency graph to avoid cuda and qt5 in the same target

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the most portable way would be using an `OBJECT` library like so:

```
add_library(deSimRunner_lib OBJECT main.cpp)
set_property(TARGET deSimRunner_lib PROPERTY POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)
add_executable(deSimRunner)
target_link_libraries(deSimRunner deSimRunner_lib)
```